# Excel+VBA+JSON+Put Requests

Tags: json, excel, vba

I don't fully understand how to properly package the category IDs I need to send to the API.

```
Sub testing()
  Dim sc As Object
  Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
  sc.Language = "JScript"

  Dim strURL As String: strURL = "https://api-sandbox.site.com/v1/customers/111111?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  Dim strRequest
  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
  Dim response As String

  XMLhttp.Open "PUT", strURL, False
  XMLhttp.setrequestheader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
  XMLhttp.send strRequest
  response = XMLhttp.responseText

End Sub
```

Objective:
Take a set of category IDs and push them to a specific client.  My current focus is just to gain understanding on how to do this with a single case.  As always any information is GREATLY appreciated.

```
https://api-sandbox.site.com/v1/customers/clientID?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The API uses JSON to TX/RX.  The format (from my understanding) for the categories would need to be:

```
{"categoryIDs" : [ 1, 2096, 2008, 2009 ]}
```

An example session from the API:

```
PUT /v1/customers/2938293/locations/39483?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.site.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "zip": "92886",
  "phone": "7147147147",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "state": "CA",
  "locationName": "Backpack Brigade",
  "isPhoneTracked": false,
  "specialOfferIsDeal": false, 
  "specialOffer": "Check out our new Summer Backpacks!",
  "folderId": "0",
  "city": "Yorba Linda",
  "id": "123",
  "customerId": "140149",
  "categoryIds": [
    90,
    833
  ],
  "suppressAddress": false,
  "address": "4345 Bastanchury Road",
  "websiteUrl": "http://backpackbrigade.com/",
  "hours":"2:12:00:PM:5:00:PM,3:12:00:PM:5:00:PM,4:12:00:PM:5:00:PM,6:12:00:PM:5:00:PM,7:12:00:PM:5:00:PM",
  "additionalHoursText": "Sunday by Appointment",
  "description": "Best Backpack Store in Southern California!",
  "twitterHandle": "backpackbrigade",
  "logo": { 
    "url": "http://cms.site.com/cms/328812732-backpack.png",
    "description": "Picture of a backpack" 
  },
  "displayLatitude": 33.8991997,
  "displayLongitude": -117.8437043,
  "emails":["admin@backpackbrigade.com"]
}
```

I can't say with certainty, but the code I provided is for handling the response mostly and it would appear that I'm not packaging anything to send with the `PUT` request.

Do the category IDs I'm sending need to be packaged as an `object` or is a `string` ok?

Comment: Your question is kind of broad - if you have a specific problem you're trying to solve it might be better to address the details directly, rather than look for general help.  PUT is just another HTTP verb, so any code examples you see out there for (eg) using XMLHTTP to POST data can likely just be re-used by substitiuting PUT in place of POST.  One reason you may not be finding "entry-level" information is that this isn't really an "entry level" task.

Comment: I know it is broad, but just this little blurb you gave is helpful!

Comment: Took your advice @TimWilliams.  I have a starting point now.  When I add `MsgBox (response)` I get an error that states: _{"errors":[{"message":"We were unable to deserialize your json request: Value must be a JSONObject (but is a class java.lang.String)"}]}_

Comment: Did you omit the part where you populate `strRequest` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not omit the part populating `strRequest`. I'm not sure how to construct the JSON to send it to the API.

Comment: What are you constructing it from, and which is it, the first or the second JSON block in your question?

Comment: I have a set of category IDs that I need to put request to replace the ones already contained in the 'account'.

The example AP session I posted is simply the put request (I didn't post the reponse).  It responds with a Status 200 code and then outputs the JSON object with the updated value.

The API only uses Path and API key for authentication.

Comment: You can store that JSON in (eg) a worksheet cell, maybe with a placeholder for the categoryId's which you can replace bfore performing the PUT. Just need to get that JSON into strRequest...  Kind of difficult for me to help much more since I can't test anything here.

Comment: This is all helpful Tim, do you have any material regarding populating `strRequest` or principles/elements that I should look into to gain more understanding?

Comment: Nothing specific I can suggest, other than read up a bit on JSON - what it is and how it's structured. In the end it's just a string of text like the example you posted.

Comment: JSON seems quite simple.  The issue I have is more VBA-related I assume dealing with handling the different data types.  

I have it in my head to figure this out and I know there will be others who will benefit from me figuring this out.

Again much appreciated Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to use JSON and EXCEL I highly recommend this website as a resource: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json

The modules that Bruce Mcpherson has put together here makes PUT requests, sorting and saving data from JSON API calls simple and straight forward.

I hope this helps anyone that is in the same situation I was!